# smtp send mail via postfix and nodejs nodemailer connection closed

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, postfix-mta, nodemailer

i have problem of remote sending via smtp server
using nodejs module nodemailer

```
host: 'mail.5cpa.ru'
port: 587
secure: false (true tried also)
```

smtp server is mine, and i can send mails through thenderbird, using same setting

log

```
server 220 5cpa.ru ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
client EHLO vonica
server 250-5cpa.ru
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 15728640
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
client STARTTLS
server 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
socket Closing connection to the server
```

thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar problem (maybe the same) and I figure out that this happens when i use self signed SSL certificate.
I fixed this by adding "rejectUnauthorized" option to tls:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: host,
    port: 25,
    auth: {
        user: user,
        pass: pass
    },
    tls:{
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
}));
```

The error is applied to the callback of "sendMail" function and is not emitted as 'error'.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to reply above, but you could also check the latest syntax from Nodemailer, ie:

```
 const smtpConfig = {
     host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
     port: 465,
     secure: true, // use SSL
     auth: {
       user: 'user@gmail.com',
       pass: 'pass'
     }
 }
```

> note:

```
 secure: true // use SSL
```

You might not need that TLS work-around if you tell it to use SSL.

Reference: https://nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/setup-smtp/

Mine is currently running off postfix and mailx, and I only had to put in the hostname:

```
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          name: 'localhost'
 })
```

That should work as long as you can perform this test (type in shell):

```
 echo "Email Body Test" | mail -s "Email Subject Test" you@yourdomain.com
```

If it doesn't work, investigate your firewall, port 25 (probably not the issue in this case, but in other similar cases).

Also confirm the user running node has permission to use the mail program.

Comment: thanks a lot. Just a tiny question: when you use local postfix, you just need to `nodemailer.createTransport({ name: 'localhost' })`?

Comment: I don't know, good luck :)